# SHA1 with RSA using private key in c#

Tags: c#, rsa, sha1, digital-certificate

I've tried this

```
X509Certificate2 _MiCertificado = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\Lefczuk\Downloads\KitPruebas SW\CSD Pruebas\aad990814bp7_1210261233s.cer", "12345678a",X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA1 = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)_MiCertificado.PrivateKey;

SHA1 hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
UTF8Encoding e = new UTF8Encoding(true);
byte[] bytesFirmados = RSA1.SignData(e.GetBytes(this.obtenerCadenaOriginal()),hasher);
Convert.ToBase64String(bytesFirmados);
```

but it throws a NullReferenceException, RSA1 object is null.

Is there a way to to solve this problem without using .psk or .p12 files or without writing OpenSSL commands?

Answer (score 2):

Certificate (.cer) files such as the one you are loading do not contain private keys, hence `_MiCertificado.PrivateKey` is null (which is why `RSA1` is also null). You cannot sign data without a private key, and so you're going to have to load a file that contains one (such as a .p12).